# Android studio: Rabbitmq: Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry not found

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq

I'm little bit new in RabbitMQ. I followed this links https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-07-29-rabbitmq-on-android.html
But when I want to start my project the Gradle Build failed with next error message:

> Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry not found.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebugdthome'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\39.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\40.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\40.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\41.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\16.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\17.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\25.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\26.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\0.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\1.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\35.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\36.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\19.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\20.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\20.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\21.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\32.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\33.jar --input C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\7.jar --output C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debugdthome\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\classes\debugdthome --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\9.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\10.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\16.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\17.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\18.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\19.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\20.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\21.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\22.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\23.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\24.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\25.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\26.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\27.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\28.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\29.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\30.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\31.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\32.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\33.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\34.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\35.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\36.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\37.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\38.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\39.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debugdthome\40.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\deakt\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 21 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.10'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.MFlisar:RXBus:1.0'
    compile 'com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/amqp-client-5.2.0.jar')
}
```

I already tried these links but it isn't helped for me:

[Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.openjdk.jdi.ReferenceType not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216842/errorjava-lang-classnotfoundexception-class-org-openjdk-jdi-referencetype-not)
[Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.openjdk.jdi.ReferenceType not found when update android studio 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302567/errorjava-lang-classnotfoundexception-class-org-openjdk-jdi-referencetype-not)

Can Anybody tell me some suggestion?

Comment: have you ever used https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer before?

Comment: @MohammadTabbara No I don't used it.

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/issues/355 it seems similar issue that was closed.

Comment: @MohammadTabbara Yeah, but here doesn't have any solution.

Comment: Did you try to go for example with an order release as 5.1.2 or is it the same? btw https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/-DN17_BtRWc the last poster maybe can help you if you can reproduce in a new project.

Comment: @MohammadTabbara Yeah I tried an order release but doesn't help :(
EDIT: My project, before add the RabbitMQ Java client dependency, was building successfully, but when I add that dependency I got the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Anybody else can help me? :=(

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I used the 5.2.0 version of the library. Going back to 4.6.0 solved the issue for me.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/4.6.0/

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from [lambda desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) in Android SDK. You can disable it by adding the following to your `gradle.properties` file:

`android.enableDesugar=false`

lint can then complain and abort the build, you can avoid this by adding the following in the `android` section of the `build.gradle` file:

`lintOptions {
     abortOnError false
}`